# ORM Query with multiple LEFT joins

Tags: python, django, django-models

*Toy example:* Let's say I have the following models:

```
# Person ---lives_in--> City ---part_of---> State

class Person(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lives_in = models.ForeignKey('City', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class City(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    part_of = models.ForeignKey('State', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

How do I get a list of people who live in a particular state using Django ORM?

In regular SQL, it be something like

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM person p
LEFT JOIN city c ON (p.lives_in = c.id)
LEFT JOIN state s ON (c.part_of = s.id)
WHERE c.name = 'MA'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply traverse through the relationships using `__` notation.

```
people_in_ma = Person.objects.filter(lives_in__part_of__name="MA")
```

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships